# How do I make cron work with a specific app engine module?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have an `app.yaml` as below:

```
application: myapp
module: mymodule
version: 1 
runtime: python27 
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
...
```

The app also has a `cron.yaml` as below:

```
cron:
- description: increase a value every hour
  url: /test/inc
  schedule: every 60 minutes synchronized
```

How do I make my cron job target `mymodule` instead of the `default` module?

Comment: You can use dispatch.yaml  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing

Comment: This does not seem to work. I have a dispatch.yaml alongside my cron.yaml with:

Comment: Ignore the last comment. This does work but you need to run `$PATH_TO_SDK/appcfg.py update_dispatch` after creating/editing your `dispatch.yaml` file. The documentation does not seem to mention this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In newer versions of GAE (tested at least with 1.8.6), you can just set the **target** for your cron task:

```
cron:
- description: increase a value every hour
  url: /test/inc
  schedule: every 60 minutes synchronized
  target: mymodule
```

Comment: I'm on 1.8.8 and it doesn't seem to work for me. Tried restarting server too.

Comment: Does your module handle the request url? Do you get any entry log in it? Whaat does the cron page tell about the status?

Comment: Yes, according to stdout, cron is making request to `default` and not `api` module, despite the fact that my cron.yaml task has `target: api` setting.

Comment: long shot: are you sure you updated your cron file with update_cron? it no longer works by just deploying the app

Comment: It works in production, it just doesn't work on dev server (localhost:8000/cron).

Comment: Oh, in that case, you'll have to test your cron by hitting the URL instead of clicking the button in the cron's page (seems like a dev_appserver bug, as it doesn't honor the *target* parameter when building the url it invokes)

Comment: @marianosimone Do you know how I can target a particular version of a particular module?

Comment: @Bugs in theory, using target: version:module should do the trick (check api/cronifo.py and api/taskqueue.py), but I couldn't make it work

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @voscausa you can use a `dispatch.yaml` file https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing to route a cron job to the right module.

Make sure you run `appcfg.py update_dispatch` after you create the `dispatch.yaml` file.